# R: Split Dataset by randomizing group variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset that I need to split into a training and test set in R. It has many observations, and each have a value for their respective time (Q32008, Q42008,...,Q42016).

I want to split the dataset in half, using randomized quarters, where all observations for a specific quarter are together. For example, one dataset would have all observations from Q2 2009, Q4 2010, Q1 2008. I tried using `split`, but I could not `unsplit` it randomly, into 2 unique datasets.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about  [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and how to give a  [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) . This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood what you meant. Is the code below helpful?

```
my.df = expand.grid(Quarter=paste0("Q",1:4),Year=2012:2016)
my.df$Period = with(my.df,paste0(Quarter,Year))
my.df$x = rnorm(nrow(my.df))

# Randomly select periods for different data frames
first.periods = sample(my.df$Period,nrow(my.df)/2)
my.df$SplitID = as.numeric(my.df$Period %in% first.periods)+1

# Split data frame
split.df = split(x = my.df,f = my.df$SplitID)
```